# Cambiar el nombre de una variable en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: java

El caso es que tengo un **GUI**, con diferentes `CheckBox` y necesitaba comprobar cada uno de los diferentes `CheckBox` que tengo para saber si están pulsados o no.

Cada uno de ellos tiene un nombre del tipo `CHECKBOX_1`, `CHECKBOX_2` etc. El caso es que me gustaría recorrer de una forma semiautomática todos ellos variando únicamente el número del final.

¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo?

Gracias.

Comment: No se puede cambiar el nombre de una variable. Se me ocurre que podes crear nuevas o cambiar el puntero de cada una de las variables, es decir, que la variable2 apunte al checkbox3 y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Para hacer lo que te comente arriba, te conviene tenerlas en un array.

Comment: Despues de meterlas a un array puedes recorrerlas con un for each facilmente

Answer (score 2):

En Java, durante tiempo de ejecución, no se tiene información de los nombres de las variables locales utilizadas en los métodos. Si necesitas acceder a las variables de manera dinámica puedes almacenarlas en un  arreglo o en contenedor como `List` o `Map` y luego acceder a la variable por un índice (arreglo y lista) o nombre (en el caso de mapa).